# decomposing elements of the Lie group $SO(n)$ by means of diagonalization

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am reading the proof of the *corollary 0.2* of this link https://www.math.tamu.edu/~rojas/son.pdf and several questions arise. I would like to know what the $\Lambda$ matrix is ​​like, I don't know very well how this matrix is ​​composed graphically, could someone show me what this matrix looks like for a specific dimension?

Answer (score 1):

$\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix, which means that even though it has $n^2$ entries, the vast majority of the entries equal zero. Only the $n$ entries on the diagonal are non-zero. The entries of $\Lambda$ on the diagonal are not limited to being real numbers - they may also be complex, i.e. of the form $a+bi$ for some numbers $a$ and $b$, and $i=\sqrt{-1}$ is the imaginary unit. Even further, when plotted at $(a,b)$ on the plane these complex numbers lie on the unit circle, which is equivalent to saying that $a^2+b^2=1$. Thus, when the non-zero entries of $\Lambda$ are plotted in the complex plane, they become $n$ points on the unit circle (circle of radius $1$ centered at the origin).

Geometrically, the values on the diagonal of $\Lambda$ represent its [eigenvalues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors). Since they are complex numbers on the unit circle, they can be written as $e^{i\theta}$, where $\theta$ represents an angle (in radians). In fact, the non-real eigenvalues come in pairs $e^{\pm i\theta}$, corresponding to a 2-dimensional eigenspace, and the vectors in that eigenspace are rotated by an angle of $\pm\theta$.

Comment: I understand everything until $S^*\begin{bmatrix} \lambda& 0\\ 0 & \bar{\lambda}\end{bmatrix}S$. Then from there I do not understand what is done. Why is $\Sigma$ taken this way? How is the matrix $\Sigma$ (what does that look like)? Why is $\Sigma\Lambda\Sigma^*$ the matrix we need?

Comment: Could you make a better proof of this please where the details are better explained? Thank you.

Comment: What are the possible eigenvalues ​​for a matrix of $SO(n)$? Are $e^{\pm i\theta}$ and $1$? Or also $-1$?